Session value returns to NULL (after setting it in the server side using React Axios)
I am making a sign in page using react.js as front end and express.js and node.js as the middleware. I wrote the signin API in the express node side, so in react when I hit submit button it calls the axios method that calls the API that handles the signin feature and there it sets the session id as the user id logged in. I also wrote an axios method that handles session id logging immediately after the submit button. The issue it returns as null (in my case Not Signed In). But after testing with POSTMAN it seems like it is working perfectly fine. I am not sure my code looks like this
On the server side
server.js (main express - node file)
const express = require('express');
const cors = require("cors");
const session = require('express-session');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const app = express();

var corsOptions = {
    origin: ["http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:3000/signin"]
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Generate a random secret key
const secretKey = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex');

app.use(session({
    secret: secretKey,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.get('/api/auth', (req, res) => {
    let userId = req.session.userId;
    // console.log('UserId : ' + userId);
    if (!userId) {
        userId = "Not Signed In";
    }
    res.json({ message: userId });
    console.log(userId);
});

const PORT = 4000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});

NOTE : 3000 is the port where I am running the react and 4000 is the port where the server is running.
Now the signin feature in my controller file
controller/customer.js
exports.signin = async (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    // console.log(req.body);
    try {
        // Find user by username
        const user = await db.customer.findOne({ where: { username } });

        // If user not found, send error response
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid username or password.' });
        }

        // Compare passwords
        const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

        // If passwords match, sign-in successful
        if (isMatch) {
            // You can include additional user information in the response if needed
            req.session.userId = user.id;
            console.log(req.session.userId);
            return res.status(200).json({ success: true, userId: user.id });
        } else {
            // If passwords don't match, send error response
            return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid username or password.' });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'An unexpected error occurred.' });
    }
};

As you see when the credentials matches it sets the session id as the logged in user id and return success.
Now react side
signin.js
function Signin() {
    const [user, setCredentials] = useState({ username: '', password: '' });
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleInputChange = (event) => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        setCredentials(prev => ({ ...prev, [name]: value }));
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setMessage('');
        const req = {
            username: user.username,
            password: user.password
        }

        try {
            const response = await userAPI.signin(req);
            const output = response.data;
            console.log(output);
            setMessage("Log In Sucessfull !!!");
            console.log(userAPI.getSession())
        }
        catch (error) {
            setMessage("Error : Invalid Credentials.");
        }

    };

  return(
   <div>Running</div>
  );

}

export default Signin

In the above file I have used axios api like userAPI.signin(req) which posts the credentials to the server side which works 100 percent and userAPI.getSession() is where it gets the session id after signin in which calls the url on localhost:4000/api/auth
app.get('/api/auth', (req, res) => {
    let userId = req.session.userId;
    // console.log('UserId : ' + userId);
    if (!userId) {
        userId = "Not Signed In";
    }
    res.json({ message: userId });
    console.log(userId);
});

Not sure In while sending the requests in postman it works 100 percent at all times. Not sure when I use the post method for signin (localhost:4000/api/customers/signin) it signs in the with lets say userID 5 and when I use get method in POSTMAN via localhost:4000/api/auth it returns as 5 but when I copy paste the url in my browser it is displaying it as Not signed in. Not sure whether my approach is wrong but using react axios to retrieve the session id it always return as Not Signed In, which is implemented in the signin page after the successfully signin in.
Please feel free to give me an alternative solution since my main goal is when a user is signed in it should able to do profile management operations. Cheers :-)
